# How to choose a variable depending on the width and height of the element?

Tags: flutter, dart, button, text, dynamic

I have two variables displaying text vertically or horizontally

```
 final String buttonTextHorizontal = 'TEXT';

 final String buttonTextVertical = 'TEXT';
    verticalText(buttonTextVertical){
      List<String>verticalTextButton = buttonTextVertical.trim().split('');
      final String newbuttonTextVertical = verticalTextButton.join("\n");
      return newbuttonTextVertical;
    }
```

I want to pass these variables to ElevatedButton

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {});
          },
            child: Text(
              // buttonTextHorizontal,
              // verticalText(buttonTextVertical),
            ),
        ),
```

I would like the text to be vertical if the height of the button is greater than the width and vice versa. The size of the button is randomly generated

```
final String buttonTextHorizontal = 'TEXT';
    
     final String buttonTextVertical = 'TEXT';
        verticalText(buttonTextVertical){
          List<String>verticalTextButton = buttonTextVertical.trim().split('');
          final String newbuttonTextVertical = verticalTextButton.join("\n");
          return newbuttonTextVertical;
        }

    return Positioned(
      height: randomHeight.toDouble(),
      width: randomWidth.toDouble(),
      child: SizedBox(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {});
          },
            child: Text(
              // buttonTextHorizontal,
              // verticalText(buttonTextVertical),
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The size of the button is randomly generated and when you click on it, the button changes its initial size (the width may become greater than the height and vice versa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LayoutBuilder` to get parent size.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        //ignoring ==
        final bool isHeightGreater = constraints.maxHeight > constraints.maxWidth;
        return Text(isHeightGreater ? "Height is larger"
            : "width is larger",
           style:TextStyle(...)
          );
      },
    )),
```

Also make sure `ElevatedButton` is getting proper size.

Comment: your option works, but I need the spelling of the text to also change depending on the size, so I need to pass my variables that change the spelling of the text, and not just the text

Comment: Yes you can do that, use a bool in this case and perform your logic to represent the text

Comment: Glad to help you out. You can find more about [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html):

> Builds a widget tree that can depend on the parent widget's size.
>
> Similar to the Builder widget except that the framework calls the
> builder function at layout time and provides the parent widget's
> constraints. This is useful when the parent constrains the child's
> size and doesn't depend on the child's intrinsic size. The
> LayoutBuilder's final size will match its child's size.

Maybe something like this:

```dart
  child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          if (constraints.maxWidth > constraints.maxHeight) {
            return HorizontalText();
          } else {
            return VerticalText();
          }
        },
      ),
```